# What does this symbolise with reference to Intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've read the following for Android Intents:

> Think of Intents as a verb and object; a description of what you want done –
>   E.g. VIEW, CALL, PLAY etc.

I am not able to understand this sentence. Can anyone please explain me this? I know that An Intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try and explain. You use an Intent when you want a particular activity in your application to do something. The action that you want to perform is specified as the Intent itself (Like play music, call someone, take a photo). Verbs are something which represent any action. Intents also represent actions that you app will do with the help of activities and intents.

Also intents always need an object to perform the desired action which is an argument in the Intent. Hence the destination class object in the Intent is the is description (it contains all the detailed methods of the operation to be performed).

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Intent transport infomation between 2 Activity, amagine it's like a transporter send mail, gift, information... between you and I.

So, I want to send you a PhoneNumber and I need you call this number. So the transporter need your name, address,... (--> It's like setClassName() in Intent) and action i want you do (--> like ACTION in Intent). After that, the transporter will send infomation to you and you will call the phonenumber for me.